# Redirecting the login Page to different page for 2nd time

Tags: angularjs

I have a registration form , after I register, I am redirected to Login page and login with mail and password. I need my page to redirect  to welcome page after register and from second time to login it should display my profile details page.
How is it possible in angular Js. please do assist.

Answer (score 0):

here is one thing you can do , in your server code , when a user registers redirect him to welcome page , and after login redirect him to profile page , this way user will see welcome page only once ( just after registering )